# Nested .bind not working as expected

Tags: javascript, closures, call, bind, nested-function

Unfortunately `.bind` has been giving me grief when creating more complex closures.

I am quite interested in why .bind seems to work differently once you nest functions.

For example :

```
function t(){
    t = t.bind({}); //correctly assigns *this* to t  
    function nested_t(){
        nested_t = nested_t.bind({}); // fails to assign *this* to nested_t
        return nested_t; 
    }
    return nested_t(); 
}
//CASE ONE
alert(t()); 
          // alerts the whole function t instead of nested_t

//CASE TWO
aleft(t.call(t)); 
         // alerts the global object (window)
```

In both cases I was expecting a behavior like this:

```
function t(){
    var nested_t = function nested_t(){
        return this;
    };
    return nested_t.call(nested_t);
}

alert(t.call(t));
```

If someone could explain the behavior of `.bind` in the first (and/or) second case it would be much appreciated!

Comment: In both cases i get `window`. :/

Comment: A function that overwrites itself when being called. What horror have you done?!

Comment: Your first case is irreproducable. As expected, both calls to `t()` do return the global object, which is the `this` context of the `nested_t()` call. They would return `undefined` if you used strict mode.

Comment: @Bergi I understand a self-overwriting function does not make much sense in this example. But nested `bind/call` can be quite useful in creating complex closures : deferred based callbacks : and some interfaces. (The example above was just the simplest way of demonstrating it)

Comment: I didn't think the first argument of bind was optional, surly without it it has no effect? - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh `.bind({})` just binds the subject to a new object. AKA `this = {}`

Comment: @Burdocksorry Sorry, I misread the code and thought you were just calling .bind() without the literal object.

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh No problem, I understand my example does not make a whole lot of sense this far out of context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, i'm not entirely reproducing your issue here (both cases return the global object), but i'll try and explain the code as i see it.

```
function t(){
    t = t.bind({}); //correctly assigns *this* to t  
    function nested_t(){
        nested_t = nested_t.bind({}); // fails to assign *this* to nested_t
        return this; 
    }
    return nested_t(); 
}
//CASE ONE
alert(t());
```

Let's take it step by step.

First, the function `t()` is defined. Then, *upon call*, it gets overwritten with a clean context. However, i don't see any usage of this context.

Now, a nested function (`nested_t`) is defined. *Upon call*, it is overwritten with a clean context. It then returns the context it had *when it was called*.

Back to `t()`. You then return the *result* of `nested_t()`, **not** `nested_t` itself. In the original function call, `nested_t` is still being called with global context.

Therefore, when you run `t()`, it returns the global object.

Comment: Intresting : it looks like this may be an issue with my development environment (Appcelorator).

Comment: I ran it in Chrome's console.

Comment: Im getting the same thing in Chrome : DX I guess it was just an issue with Appcelorator

Comment: *facepalm* yep .... Thanks anyway though .... looks like Appcelorator's .bind is acting recursive when it should not be.

Answer (score 2):

### How your code works

It's very unclear, what your code is trying to do. You can find the documentation for `.bind()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). It looks like you might be somehow misunderstanding what `this` is and how to use it. Anyway, what happens when you run your code is this:

1. A `t` function is created in global scope.
2. *[case one]* The `t` function is called.

   1. Global scope `t` is replaced with a new value (original `t` bound to a specific context - anonymous empty object), which **doesn't affect the current call in any way**. Also, while the global `t` is overwritten, **the local `t` is behaving as read-only**. You can check it out by trying the following code: `(function foo () { return (function bar () { bar = window.bar = 'baz'; return bar; })(); })()` and comparing return value with `window.bar`.
   2. The same thing happens with `nested_t` in the nested context (instead of global context).
   3. Result of `nested_t` call is returned. `nested_t` returns the context it was called with, which was `window`, as no context was specified. Specifically, it was not called with an empty object context, because the `.bind()` inside didn't affect the call itself.
3. *[case two]* The exact same thing happens once again. Now you're just calling `t` with itself as context. Since `t` doesn't use its context (`this`) anywhere in its code, nothing really changes.

---

### What your misconceptions might be

Basically, you're mixing up two things - function instance and function call context. A function is a "first-class citizen" in JavaScript - it's an object and you can assign values to its properties.

```
function foo () {
    foo.property = 'value';
}
foo();    // foo.property is assigned a value
```

This has nothing to do with function call context. When you call a function a context is assigned to **that call**, which can be accessed using `this` (inside function body)

```
function foo () {
    this.property = 'value';
}
var object = {};
foo.call(object);    // object.property is assigned a value
```

When you use `.bind()`, you just create a new function with the same code, that is locked to a specific context.

```
function foo () {
    this.property = 'value';
}
var fixedContext = {},
    object = {};
bar = foo.bind(fixedContext);
foo.call(object);    // fixedContext.property is set instead of object.property
```

But in this case, there are also function instances `foo` and `bar`, which can also be assigned properties, and which have nothing to do with contexts of calls of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at how `bind` works.  First, one level of nesting:

```
var foo = function() { return this.x; };
alert(foo());  // undefined
alert(foo.bind({x: 42})()); // 42
```

Now we can add the next level of nesting:

```
var bar = function() { return foo.bind(this)(); };
alert(bar());  // undefined
alert(bar.bind({x: 42})());
```

We pass our `this` context to `foo` with - guess what? - `bind`.  There is nothing different about the way `bind` works between scopes.  The only difference is that we've already bound `this` within `bar`, and so the body of `bar` is free to re-bind `this` within `foo`.

As a couple of commenters have noted, functions that overwrite themselves are a huge code smell.  There is no reason to do this; you can `bind` context to your functions when you call them.

I highly, highly recommend reading [the documentation on `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), and trying to understand it *to the point where you can write a basic version of `Function.prototype.bind` from scratch*.

Comment: A recursive .bind was just the best example of the issue. Deferred based callbacks in appcelerator often benefit from calling `.bind` on `this/that/` some other nested object pointer.

Comment: Basically, it looks like it was a appcelerator development environment  issue due to in converting javascript into java/obj-c/C#/ and so on.